# Circles está sobrepondo Merkers impossibilitando clicks (Google maps API JavaScript)

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-maps-api-3

No Google maps API JavaScript, ao utilizar o objeto Circles o mesmo sobrepõe o meu Layer do Fusion Tables impossibilitando de clicar nos markers e abrir a infoWindow e etc de cada marker.

Já experimentei chamar o circle antes da chamada do fusion tables, sem sucesso. Também experimentei colocar ZIndex nos markers e continuou a mesma coisa..

OBS: quando utilizo um marker normal sem o ser do layer o marker fica a cima do circle e funciona normal.. somente o layer que fica a baixo do circle. 
Segue um print da tela demonstrando a sobreposição do circle em relação ao marker do layer:

[image: A imagem mostra que o circulo está sobrepondo o marker do layer(maker branquinho).. o marker normal(icone com um carinha) está funcionando]

E segue um pedaço do codigo demonstrando as chamadas:

```js
 circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#0000ff',
      strokeOpacity: 0.4,
      strokeWeight: 1,
      fillColor: '#0000ff',
      fillOpacity: 0.07,
      map: map,
      center: myLocation, 
      radius: radius
    });

    //camada  do fusion table
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
     query: {
       select: '\'Location\'',
       from: tableId,
     styles: [{
        markerOptions: {
        iconName: "ylw_stars",
        zIndex:999
      }
      }
   ],
    map: map
   });
```

Comment: manda o códigopara ver.

Comment: Se colocar o código fica melhor. Em um projeto que fiz eu usei zIndex e deu certo. Coloque o zIndex alto nas propriedades do marker quando for cria-lo e um zIndex mais baixo para o Circle

Comment: Galera perdão pela pergunta meio vaga e sem o codigo..Atualizei e expliquei melhor meu problema..